# Qual è il significato di "sondare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Cercai di illustrarti i meccanismi della mia psicologia, ma probabilmente il mio inglese non era sufficiente per **sondare** le sottigliezze della mia irrequietudine, la biologica inadeguatezza a tenere una rotta ferma nei sentimenti e nei comportamenti.

Il mio dubbio è sul significato del verbo "sondare" in questa frase. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sondare/) ho trovato questa accezione:

> **2**. fig. Cercare di conoscere in anticipo, senza manifestare interamente i proprî intendimenti, la disponibilità, le intenzioni, le reazioni di una o più persone relativamente a una data proposta o iniziativa: *ho sondato le intenzioni di tuo padre; il presidente incaricato di formare il governo ha sondato i segretarî dei partiti di maggioranza; s. l’opinione pubblica su un tema; prima di chiedere il permesso bisogna che sondi gli umori del capufficio*.

Tuttavia, dal contesto, questo verbo nel brano precedente sembra piuttosto riferirsi a qualcosa simile a "esprimersi": se non è così, non posso capire cosa c'entra che Gassman sapesse o no l'inglese. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "sondare" nel testo sopra citato?

Comment: Penso che l'accezione sia la prima: *esaminare, rilevare, esplorare con una sonda*, dove figurata è la sonda. Nota anche che si dice “sapere l'inglese”, con l'articolo.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg! Faccio la correzione. Non capisco però perché Gassman dovesse sapere l'inglese per poter esaminare, esplorare "le sottigliezze della sua irrequietudine, ...".

Comment: In quel passo si sta rivolgendo a un'altra persona, penso Shelley Winters che fu sua moglie.

Comment: @egreg: Sì, si sta rivolgendo a Shelley Winters ed è per questo che ho detto che Gassman sembra piuttosto riferirsi a qualcosa simile a "esprimersi".

Comment: In quel contesto le esplora con lei quando le dà le spiegazioni in inglese. Forse se pensi alla coppia come una singola entità, e lui passa da "interprete", il suo modo di scrivere il passaggio diventa un poco più semplice

Comment: Bene, @ErikvanDoren! Adesso capisco la frase. Potresti scriverlo come risposta? Cominciano a proliferare domande senza risposta che infatti sono state risposte nei commenti!

Comment: È un po' in interpretazione, avere qualche altro parere non sarebbe male. Cmq copio il commento tale e quale per ora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se prendiamo *sondare* come *esplorare, rilevare, esaminare*, in quel contesto sta esplorando sé stesso con lei quando le dà le spiegazioni in inglese. Forse se pensi alla coppia come una singola entità, e lui passa da "interprete", il suo modo di scrivere il passaggio diventa un poco più semplice.